# How to combine single array elements based on similar property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am looking for this logic if possible in ES6 to combine 2 array elements in single array.

Below is data coming from backend.

```
dataFromBackend = [
    {
      animal: 'Elephant',
      height: 123,
      weight: 456
    },
    {
      animal: 'Elephant',
      food: 'abc',
      sleep: 'xyz'
    },
    {
      animal: 'Tiger',
      height: 123,
      weight: 456
    },
    {
      animal: 'Tiger',
      food: 'abc',
      sleep: 'xyz'
    },
    {
      animal: 'Rabbit',
      height: 123,
      weight: 456
    }
]
```

Expected Output

```
convertedData = [
    {
      animal: 'Elephant',
      height: 123,
      weight: 456,
      food: 'abc',
      sleep: 'xyz'
    },
    {
      animal: 'Tiger',
      height: 123,
      weight: 456,
      food: 'abc',
      sleep: 'xyz'
    },
    {
      animal: 'Rabbit',
      height: 123,
      weight: 456,
      food: 'No Data',
      sleep: 'No Data'
    }
]
```

And if there is no data for certain property I have to insert 'No Data'

Answer (score 1):

I would create a function by which you can merge the obj's by giving the data and prop. `No Data` is bad practice, use the existence of key to determine if obj has value on that key (a.k.a if there is no key `food` then there is no data on that key.

```js
  dataFromBackend = [
    { animal: 'Elephant', height: 123, weight: 456 },
    { animal: 'Elephant', food: 'abc', sleep: 'xyz' },
    { animal: 'Tiger', height: 123, weight: 456 },
    { animal: 'Tiger', food: 'abc', sleep: 'xyz' },
    { animal: 'Rabbit', height: 123, weight: 456 },
  ];
  
    // prop to merge by (string), arr of objects (any: [])
 function mergeByProp(prop, arr) {
    let returnArr = [];
    for (let obj of arr) {
      if (returnArr.some((target) => target[prop] === obj[prop])) {
        let target = returnArr.find((find) => find[prop] === obj[prop]);
        Object.assign(target, { ...target, ...obj });
      } else {
        returnArr.push(obj);
      }
    }
    console.log(returnArr);
  }
  
this.mergeByProp('animal', this.dataFromBackend);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example of how to process the dataFromBackend array and how to produce the result array with elements as the merge of objects having the same value for animal property:

```js
//your input array (just with compact formatting for easier readying)
dataFromBackend = [
    { animal: 'Elephant', height: 123, weight: 456 },
    { animal: 'Elephant', food: 'abc', sleep: 'xyz' },
    { animal: 'Tiger', height: 123, weight: 456 },
    { animal: 'Tiger', food: 'abc', sleep: 'xyz' },
    { animal: 'Rabbit', height: 123, weight: 456 }
]

expectedAnimalProperties = ['animal','height','weight','food','sleep'];

//the map will be a temporary object
var map = {};

//for each element in the input array
dataFromBackend.forEach( (o, i) => {
  //if there's yet no animal in map like o.animal
  if(typeof map[o.animal] === 'undefined')
    //init the animal inside the map
    map[o.animal] = o;
  //else if the animal already existed in the map
  else      
    //integrate the properties of the object stored in map
    map[o.animal] = {...map[o.animal], ...o};
});

//print the map to console
console.log(map);

//the result array
var result = [];
//for each key in map
Object.keys(map).forEach((k) => {
    //push the merged animal in the result array
    result.push( map[k] );
});

//print the result array
console.log(result);

//for each animal (merged) in result
result.forEach((oAnimal, iAnimal) => {
  //for each properties expected from an animal object
  expectedAnimalProperties.forEach((oExpectedKey, iExpectedKey) => {
    //if that property isn't included in the current animal
    if( !Object.keys(oAnimal).includes(oExpectedKey) ){
        //add that property to the current animal with no data
        oAnimal[oExpectedKey] = 'No Data';
    }
  });
});

//print the result array
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It won't add No Data for unmatched key

Comment: I see another answer arrived in the queue that probably addressed that concern you highlighted. Yes it changes the logic because it assumes the whole set of properties are known in advance. I didn't consider it at first. I think my answer is not helpful anymore

Comment: You have lots of choice now so it will be pointless but I have updated my answer to process the final result and integrating the missing properties using No Data as value

Answer (score 0):

I would use [the reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group the elements by the `animal` property at first, and then go through them a second time to assign the missing properties with `'No Data'`:

```js
dataFromBackend = [
    { animal: 'Elephant', height: 123, weight: 456 },
    { animal: 'Elephant', food: 'abc', sleep: 'xyz' },
    { animal: 'Tiger', height: 123, weight: 456 },
    { animal: 'Tiger', food: 'abc', sleep: 'xyz' },
    { animal: 'Rabbit', height: 123, weight: 456 }
];

let rawResult = dataFromBackend .reduce((acc, element) => {
  if (!acc[element.animal]) {
    acc[element.animal] = element
  }
  acc[element.animal] = { ...acc[element.animal], ...element }
  return acc;
}, {});

let convertedData = Object.values(rawResult).map(r => ({
  ...r,
  food: r.food ?? 'No Data',
  sleep: r.sleep ?? 'No Data'
}));

console.log(convertedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would construct a dictionary and group all animals by name, and then merge them with the spread operator

```js
type Animal = {
  animal: string;
  height?: number | string;
  weight?: number | string;
  food?: string;
  sleep?: string;
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-one',
  templateUrl: './one.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./one.component.scss'],
})
export class OneComponent {
  dataFromBackend: Animal[] = [
    { animal: 'Elephant', height: 123, weight: 456 },
    { animal: 'Elephant', food: 'abc', sleep: 'xyz' },
    { animal: 'Tiger', height: 123, weight: 456 },
    { animal: 'Tiger', food: 'abc', sleep: 'xyz' },
    { animal: 'Rabbit', height: 123, weight: 456 },
  ];

  convertedData: Animal[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    const animalDict: { [key: string]: Animal[] } = {};
    for (const el of this.dataFromBackend) {
      if (!animalDict[el.animal]) animalDict[el.animal] = [];
      animalDict[el.animal].push(el);
    }
    for (const animalName of Object.keys(animalDict)) {
      let animal: Animal = {
        animal: animalName,
        height: 'No Data',
        weight: 'No Data',
        food: 'No Data',
        sleep: 'No Data',
      };
      for (const entry of animalDict[animalName]) {
        animal = { ...animal, ...entry };
      }
      this.convertedData.push(animal);
    }
  }
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-chvdcw?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce` to merge array data with same `animal` name.
`Object.values` to convert object into array

[**more about reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const dataFromBackend = [
  { animal: 'Elephant', height: 123, weight: 456 },
  { animal: 'Elephant', food: 'abc', sleep: 'xyz' },
  { animal: 'Tiger', height: 123, weight: 456 },
  { animal: 'Tiger', food: 'abc', sleep: 'xyz' },
  { animal: 'Rabbit', height: 123, weight: 456 },
];

let mergedData = Object.values(
  dataFromBackend.reduce((acc, data) => {
    
    data.food = data.food || 'No Data';
    data.sleep = data.sleep || 'No Data';

    if (!acc[data.animal]) {
      acc[data.animal] = data;
    }
    acc[data.animal] = { ...acc[data.animal], ...data };

    return acc;
  }, {})
);
console.log(mergedData);
```